# Open file with tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here's my code for opening a new file:

```
private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFD = new OpenFileDialog();
    string Chosen_File = "";

    openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:";
    openFD.Title = "Open a Text File";
    openFD.FileName = "";

    openFD.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt|Word Documents|*.doc";

    if (openFD.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {

        Chosen_File = openFD.FileName;
        GetRichTextBox().LoadFile(Chosen_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

    }
```

I'm using tabs also. I can only open files when I have a tab opened. How can I set it to open a new tab with that file? It only works when I open a tab and then open a file.

Comment: You need each `RichTextBox` for one `TabPage`, however your `GetRichTextBox()` method of yours is a black box. Who knows you do whatever in there?

Comment: I think we need to see more code to help you there.

Comment: @Renan here's my whole Form1.cs http://paste.laravel.com/Lts

Comment: Please include only the relevant code, and include it directly in your question.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add new `TabPage` to your `TabControl` before Loading file (the way in your code):

```
TabPage tab = new TabPage(){Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Chosen_File)};
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
RichTextBox rich = new RichTextBox{Parent = tab, Dock = DockStyle.Fill};
rich.LoadFile(Chosen_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Comment: it works, but it appears that it doesn't have a title. How could I set the title of the file here?

Comment: @erm_durr where is the title?

Comment: what do you mean where is the title? I meant that when I open the file, I want the tab name be equals to the file name.

Comment: @erm_durr I mean where is the title located?

Comment: @erm_durr I think you want to show the `title` in `TabPage`, see my updated answer.